# How to define connection resource in terraform with key inline

Tags: ibm-cloud, terraform

I am using the connection resource in terraform template

```
connection {
        user = "ubuntu"
        private_key = "${file("test.pem")}"
        agent = "false" 
        timeout = "30s"
    }
```

Instead of reading the key from the file I know we can paste the key contents directly but what about the line breaks in the key string. How to paste the contents inline?

Comment: Why? Do you not want the private key on disc?

Comment: I am using Bluemix cloud automation manager where I can use only one .tf file. There is no folder structure as such where I can put files. Is there any other way I can load .pem file in the same .tf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although keeping private key information directly inside configuration is not a best-practice, it is possible to use the "heredoc" multi-line string style to include multi-line strings:

```
connection {
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = <<-EOK
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOK
    agent = "false" 
    timeout = "30s"
}
```

The `EOK` string here is an arbitrary marker chosen because it does not exist in the key, and is intended to stand for "End of key". You can choose any label you like as long as the introducer and the end marker match.

---

If the machine that is being connected to is created within the same Terraform configuration as the one where it is being provisioned (which is usually the case) an alternative is to generate dynamically a key at creation time, thus avoiding the need to place a literal key in the configuration. [The `tls_private_key` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/tls/r/private_key.html) can be used to do this:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
}

resource "some_compute_resource" "example" {
  # question didn't specify which provider is in use, so this is a generalized example
  public_key = "${tls_private_key.example.public_key_openssh}"

  connection {
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem}"
    agent       = false
    timeout     = "30s"
  }
}
```

In this case, the generated private key is saved as part of the Terraform *state* rather than as part of the configuration. This means the configuration does not contain any sensitive information and can thus be more freely shared, but it is important to ensure that the state file is stored securely to prevent unauthorized access to the created instance.

Comment: This helps. What if I have another private key which is not used to make an ssh connection to the server but to authenticate to a server software. For eg: Chef provisioner where I have a key `user_key        = "${file("chefserver.pem")}"`  to authenticate to chef server while doing chef client installation. This cannot be generated at run time whenever I install a chef client. I am using AWS provisioner.

Comment: The "heredoc" syntax in the first part of my answer can be used to populate _any_ argument, so you could also use it to populate the `user_key` argument to the chef provisioner.

Comment: Is there any way I can skip using heredoc for private key. This might be a security threat.

Comment: The Bluemix limitation of being only allowed to have one file is the constraining problem here. Terraform would normally support this just fine. You may be able to achieve this by factoring out the resources into a separate module and then making your root module in bluemux just be a `module` block referring to it, though I'm not familiar enough with bluemix to know if that is supported, and indeed publishing a module with sensitive keys in it may be problematic.

Comment: I am planning to use vault then. Because I don't think I can upload private keys anywhere.But again that would require me to populate vault on my own , manually may be.

Comment: Indeed often populating Vault initially is a manual process, since you have to start _somewhere_. Terraform does have a Vault provider, but to use it you'd probably want to run Terraform locally on your computer and then either discard the state or store it somewhere securely, but unless you have _many_ secrets to import, using the Vault CLI directly is likely simpler. Note that if you read from Vault with Terraform the secrets read will be stored in the Terraform state, so the state of the reader will need to be stored securely.